# json record from javascript, espace empty record

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json, forms

I wish to record input into my form in JSON array, but I don't know why it records empty items with "{}" and that's bug my view form when I want to use it after.

My javascript code :

```
function update_CF_Data(CF_SortablesForm){
    var mySelector = $("#cf-sortables-form");
    var data_array = new Array();
    $("#cf-sortables-form :input").not("#cf-sortables-form :input[class=optionprix]").each(function(){

        var optionPrix = $(this).siblings("input.optionprix").val();
        var item = {};
        item['name'] = $(this).attr('name');
        item['value'] = $(this).attr('value');

        if ($(this).hasClass('optionname')){
        item['optionprix'] = optionPrix;
        }

        data_array.push(item);

    });
    var sortableContent = JSON.stringify(data_array);
    $('#custom_fields').val(sortableContent);

};
```

The html form :

```
<form id="cf-sortables-form">
<ul>
    <li class="ui-state-default">
    <small>Radio Buttons</small>
    <p><input class="cf-required-checkbox" checked="checked" type="checkbox" name="required---4969523" id="required---4969523"> <label for="required---4969523">Champs Obligatoire</label></p>
    <input type="text" name="radio-buttons-label---4969523___required" value="Utilisateurs :">
        <ul id="cf-radio-buttons" class="ui-sortable">
        <li class="ui-state-default">
            <input type="text" class="optionname" name="single-radio-button---4969523" value="1 ou 2">
            <img src="images/icon-euro.png" alt="Prix" width="16" height="16">
            <input type="text" class="optionprix" name="single-radio-button---4969523" value="0">
            </li>
        </ul>
    <button class="cfButton button" data-type="single-radio-button"><i class="booked-icon booked-icon-plus"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Radio Button</button>
    </li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">
    <small>Checkboxes</small>
    <p><input class="cf-required-checkbox" checked="checked" type="checkbox" name="required---8940009" id="required---8940009"> <label for="required---8940009">Champs Obligatoire</label></p>
    <input type="text" name="checkboxes-label---8940009___required" value="Options Payantes :">
        <ul id="cf-checkboxes" class="ui-sortable">                         
            <li class="ui-state-default">
            <input type="text" class="optionname" name="single-checkbox---8940009" value="Option 1" optionprix="5">
            <img src="images/icon-euro.png" alt="Prix" width="16" height="16">
            <input type="text" class="optionprix" name="single-checkbox---8940009" value="5">
            </li>                         
        </ul>
    <button class="cfButton button" data-type="single-checkbox"><i class="booked-icon booked-icon-plus"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Checkbox</button>
    </li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">
    <small>Paragraphe de texte</small>
    <p><input class="cf-required-checkbox" checked="checked" type="checkbox" name="required---6402519" id="required---6402519"> <label for="required---6402519">Champs Obligatoire</label></p>
    <input type="text" name="paragraph-text-label---6402519___required" value="Remarque éventuelle :">
    </li>
</ul>
</form>
```

The JSON record array :

```
[{\"name\":\"required---4969523\",\"value\":\"on\"},{\"name\":\"radio-buttons-label---4969523___required\",\"value\":\"Utilisateurs :\"},{\"name\":\"single-radio-button---4969523\",\"value\":\"1 ou 2\",\"optionprix\":\"0\"},{},{\"name\":\"required---8940009\",\"value\":\"on\"},{\"name\":\"checkboxes-label---8940009___required\",\"value\":\"Options Payantes :\"},{\"name\":\"single-checkbox---8940009\",\"value\":\"Option 1\",\"optionprix\":\"5\"},{},{\"name\":\"required---6402519\",\"value\":\"on\"},{\"name\":\"paragraph-text-label---6402519___required\",\"value\":\"Remarque éventuelle :\"}]
```

I search by analysing each input in the form but I still don't know why it record empty array.

Perhaps I can find a way to espace / avoid the record if item equal {} ?

Comment: Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ymdwgpLz/ - I don't see any empty objects in the log. BTW those `{}` are _objects_ not _arrays_

Comment: P.s. your HTML has a few issues e.g. multiple textboxes with the same "name" attribute...you might want to take some time to tidy it up a bit.

Comment: Thanks ADyson, you helped me to see more clear with your jsfiddle.
As you wrote it wasn't problem in your exemple, it was not viewable because when I wroted my code here I removed the part causing the problem without knowing.
This part was the two buttons presents in my original code. I edited my question to show them.
I don't know why but my javascript record each button as empty objects, so I added another not condition in my jquery part and it worked fine.

Comment: Ah I see. The reason you get empty objects from those buttons is simply because they don't have "name" or "value" attributes, and those are the only things your "item" object records from the inputs. If they don't exist on the source element then no new property will be created on the "item".

Answer (score 1):

Problem fixed after found my problem was comming from "button".

I don't know why but the javascript recorded each "button" as an empty object, so I just added a new .not condition on the jquery to filter "button" and that's ok.

```
$("#cf-sortables-form :input").not("#cf-sortables-form :input[class=optionprix]").not("#cf-sortables-form :button").each(function(){
```

You can check this jsfiddle =>
http://jsfiddle.net/q8gwcor0/

Comment: if you wanted to make your code a bit less verbose and a bit more efficient when being executed, instead of using complicated "not" statements to exclude things, you could simply give all the fields you _do_ want to include the same CSS class, and then simply select all elements with that class e.g. `$(".cf-inputs")` or something